# Not able to login in itunesconnect account. It works for developer account?

Tags: app-store-connect

I am able to login in developer.apple.com but not in itunesconnect.apple.com with id already added as admin in other iTunes account. I got this error message

{"data":null,"messages":{"warn":null,"info":null,"error":[]},"statusCode":"ERROR"}.

Can you please explain me what is issue?

Thank you

Comment: i have 2 apple ids - one with an icloud account (.me) and one withe an external email address. the one with the external email address works - maybe a problem with icloud

Comment: I'm also seeing this. Unsure why. Problem at Apple's end - it ought not to return this to a browser!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have someone else, like your team Agent, sign into iTunes Connect. It'll work for them; in iTunes Connect there's a Users button. From there they can add an iTunes Connect user (which'll be you :) )

It's a shitty error message that means "you don't have access to iTunes Connect".

Comment: Cool, @jbchitaliya, the appropriate response is to mark the answer as correct then... Glad I could help!